# Wicket: Getting Tags Attribute

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, wicket

I am combining wicket and jQuery for some project.

I have in HTML:

```
<a wicket:id="link" testAttr="test"></a>
```

And using jQuery I modify this attribute when other components on the page are clicked. My question here is how to obtain the current value of attribute "testAttr" from Java? I am fetching the value on every ajax call and see with inspect element that is changed, so no problem with that.

I have tried with getMarkupAttributes() but I always get value "test" and not the current one which I see on the page with inspect element. Also tried with AttributeModifier and Appender, onComponentTag, but had no luck.

Does anybody have an idea what to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to send the current attribute value to the server as a 'dynamic extra parameter':

```
link.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("click") {
  updateAjaxAttributes(ARA ara) {
    super.updateAttributes(ara);

    ara.getDynamicExtraParameters()
            .add("return {'q' : jQuery('#' + attrs.c).attr('testAttr') };");
  }

  onEvent(ART art) {
    RequestCycle requestCycle = RequestCycle.get();
    String val = requestCycle.getRequest()
        .getRequestParameters()
        .getParameterValue("q")
        .toString();

    // ...
  }
});
```